# Link for Most Recent Post

Tags: php, single

I am trying to make a comic website that has arrows pointing to First/Previous/Next/Latest on single.php. I've linked the first 3, but I'm struggling in figuring out how to link to Latest. It doesn't feel like it should be that hard, but Google only gave me ways to link it in the menu. Here's the code I have thus far for the Comic Navigation Menu. The last image with the alt "Last" is what I need to link:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 comic-first">
        <a href="https://echomartin.com/unit418/comic/01/"><img src="https://echomartin.com/unit418/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/arrows-first.png" alt="First"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 comic-navigation">
        <?php the_post_navigation( array(
            'prev_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous Post', 'multipurpose-blog' ) . '</span> <span class="comic-previous"><span class="nav-title-icon-wrapper">' . '</span>%title</span>',
            'next_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next Post', 'multipurpose-blog' ) . '</span><span class="comic-next">%title<span class="nav-title-icon-wrapper">' . '</span></span>',
        ) ); ?>
        <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 comic-last">
        <img src="https://echomartin.com/unit418/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/arrows-last.png" alt="Last">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use `get_posts()` to get the latest post, then pass it to `get_the_permalink()` to get the URL to it:

```
<?php 
$latest_posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => 1 ) );

if ( ! empty( $latest_posts ) ) :
    $latest_post = $latest_posts[0];

    if ( $latest_post->ID !== get_the_ID() ) :
        ?>

        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink( $latest_post ); ?>"><img src="https://echomartin.com/unit418/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/arrows-last.png" alt="Last"></a>

        <?php
    endif;
endif;
?>
```

Note that I used `$latest_post->ID !== get_the_ID()` to check if we were already on the latest post, and to only output the link if we weren't.

Comment: You are the absolute best. It worked perfectly. Thank you, thank you, thank you!!